# htaccess 301 redirects appending old url to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following 301 redirect:

`Redirect 301 /specialty-services/surgery/total-hip-replacement/ https://example.com/blog/total-hip-replacement/`

But it is redirecting to:

```
https://example.com/peak-referral/#servicessurgery/total-hip-replacement/
```

This is happening on several of my redirects.

I think I need a Rewrite rule but I'm not sure. Can anyone please help?

Here is the main part of my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/peak\-referral\/" [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /specialty-services/surgery/total-hip-replacement/ https://example.com/blog/total-hip-replacement/
```

Comment: I was able to solve my own problem by using the RewriteRule: RewriteRule ^specialty\-services\/surgery\/total\-hip\-replacement\/$ "https\:\/\/ethosvet\.com\/blog\/total\-hip\-replacement\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: The directives you posted shouldn't have resulted in the redirect you were seeing, since it only matches requests for the document root (`^/?$`). However, it is correct to not mix mod_rewrite and mod_alias redirects in the same context. Also, there's no need for all those backslash escapes (that looks very cPanel-esk).